# How to enable more php extensions on Gentoo server?

Tags: linux, php, gentoo

I have working apache/php/mysql on my Gentoo server. But I have to enable some extensions in php (json, exif).

I did:

`USE="dev-lang/php json exif" emerge dev-lang/php`

Please, tell me what next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Don't include the category/package name in USE, it's just

```
USE="json exif" emerge dev-lang/php
```

But I'd suggest making that choice persistent, e.g. by adding

```
dev-lang/php apache2 json exif
```

to /etc/portage/package.use and then

```
emerge dev-lang/php
```

all modules are built into the php executable, gentoo doesn't use extension modules (.so), so this should be all you have to do. Make sure the emerge exits without errors.

Comment: Thanks, I added these lines to /etc/portage/package.use
and than,
emerge dev-lang/php
Do I have to rebuild PHP? I restarted apache but I still don't see json enabled...

Comment: You _are_ rebuilding php with `emerge dev-lang/php`. Use `emerge -pv dev-lang/php` to check the use flags.

Comment: The one and only right answer, plus helpful comments.